# Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove "New Address" from billing address drop down

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am trying to remove the "New Address" option in the billing address select.
(I don't want customers to be able to add a new billing address).

[image]

I have tried hiding it via css: `select[name="billing_address_id"]:last-child { display:none; }` and also by jQuery: `$("select[name=billing_address_id] option:last").remove();`

I have also tried removing it from vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\billing-address.js:

```
        var lastSelectedBillingAddress = null,
        //newAddressOption = {
            /**
             * Get new address label
             * @returns {String}
             */
        //    getAddressInline: function () {
        //        return $t('New Address');
        //    },
        //    customerAddressId: null
        //},
        countryData = customerData.get('directory-data'),
        addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
            return address.getType() == 'customer-address';
        });

    addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);
```

But all 3 solutions have failed.

(of course I have refreshed the cache, deployed static content, deleted pub/static/frontend/*)

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change this in inside theme or module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your following solution must be work:
***I have also tried removing it from vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\billing-address.js:***

Replace following code:

```
var lastSelectedBillingAddress = null,

    countryData = customerData.get('directory-data'),
    addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
        return address.getType() == 'customer-address';
    });

//addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);
```

Also remove pub/static/frontend/* and clear cache.

**NB: Don't modify core code directly.**

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't work though. No change.

Comment: Did you disabled your browser cache? Try to hard refresh or disable js cache.

Comment: Ahh that could be it :) Running tests now. Thanks!

Comment: @SohelRana, above code removed New address option from drop down, but when i click checkbox, a form appears to edit address, can we avoid it?

Comment: @SohelRana,I want to add please select option in drop down,can you please suggest how can do?

Answer (score 1):

The above solution is little old as code has been moved from billing-address.js to billing-adress/list.js. Please follow below steps to remove Add New Address from Billing Address dropdown.

Create Mixin:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list': {
                '<ventor_module>/js/view/billing-address-list-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then JS file:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
], function (Component, addressList, $t, customer) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            /**
             * @returns {Object} Chainable.
             */
            initConfig: function () {
                this._super();
                //Below code will pop Add New Address option from Array
                this.addressOptions.pop();
                return this;
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a requirement to remove the **New Address** button from the shipping address and billing address from shipping and Payment steps respectfully based on a flag that was set in the customerData.
To achieve this, we followed the given approach:

Override the JS and template files from **vendor/magento/module-checkout/** module to your theme folder and follow the steps given below:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js
>   [around Line no. 75]

**Add new line at: Line no. 30**

```
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
```

**Add new line at: Line no. 53**

```
shippingRateService,
customerData
```

**Now customerData is accessible.**

**Add new line at: Line No. 68**

```
displayNewAddressPopup: customerData.get('restrict_addr'),
```

after addition of this line, the code should look like:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t,
    shippingRateService,
    customerData
) {
    'use strict';

    var popUp = null;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
            shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        isFormPopUpVisible: formPopUpState.isVisible,
        isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
        isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
        saveInAddressBook: 1,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),
        displayNewAddressPopup: customerData.get('zonal_prices')().win_id,
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
>   [around Line no. 18]

**Replace:**

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
<if args="!isFormInline">
    <button type="button" class="action action-show-popup primary" click="showFormPopUp" visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
        <span translate="'New Address'" />
    </button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" visible="isFormPopUpVisible()" render="shippingFormTemplate" />
</if>
```

**With:**

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
<if args="!isFormInline">
        <if args="!displayNewAddressPopup">
            <button type="button" class="action action-show-popup primary" click="showFormPopUp" visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                <span translate="'New Address'" />
            </button>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" visible="isFormPopUpVisible()" render="shippingFormTemplate" />
        </if>
</if>
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/billing-address.js

**Add new line at: Line No. 68**

```
hideBillingAddressSwitcher: customerData.get('restrict_addr'),
```

after addition of this line, the code should look like:

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address'
    },
    currentBillingAddress: quote.billingAddress,
    addressOptions: addressOptions,
    customerHasAddresses: addressOptions.length > 1,
    hideBillingAddressSwitcher: customerData.get('restrict_addr'),
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address.html

**Replace:**

```
<div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
           data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
            data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
</div>
```

**With:**

```
<if args="!hideBillingAddressSwitcher">
        <div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
            <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
                   data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
            <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
                    data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
        </div>
</if>
```

This is how, based on the value **restrict_addr** stored in the **customerData**, we were able to hide the add new address buttons.

Note: To set the custom variable in the customerData, please refer this link: [Customer Data Management in Magento 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj_vYjK587fAhUCUI8KHXlKCVcQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbelvg.com%2Fblog%2Fcustomer-data-management-in-magento-2.html&usg=AOvVaw2aem23uHZjsn5elH0ddEsW)

Answer (score 0):

Faced with this issue. Here is my working solution based on mixin:

1. Add mixin to *"app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js"* file:

```
    var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/checkout/view/billing-address-mixin': true
            }
        }
    };
```

2. Add *"app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout/view/billing-address-mixin.js"* file:

```
    define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
        'mage/translate'
    ],
    function ($, addressList, $t) {
        'use strict';
        return function (Component) {
            return Component.extend({
                // your condition if need to add "New Address" option
                canManageAddresses: window.checkoutConfig.canManageAddresses,

                initialize: function () {
                    this.addressOptions = this.getAddressOptions();
                    return this._super();
                },

                /**
                 * Add "New Address" option only if allowed
                 * @returns {array}
                 */
                getAddressOptions: function () {
                    let newAddressOption = {
                        /**
                         * Get new address label
                         * @returns {String}
                         */
                        getAddressInline: function () {
                            return $t('New Address');
                        },
                    },
                    addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
                        return address.getType() === 'customer-address';
                    });

                    // add "New Address" option only if need !!!
                    if (this.canManageAddresses) {
                        addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);
                    }
                    return addressOptions;
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.2

All you need to do is create an override for:

view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

**in:**

app/design/frontend/<Custom_Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

**And then remove:**

```
           `<button type="button"
                    class="action action-show-popup"
                    click="showFormPopUp"
                    visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                <span translate="'New Address'" />
            </button>`
```

**Create an override for this:**

Vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js

**Add it here:**

app/design/frontend/<Custom_Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/js/shipping-address/list.js

**Change**
initChildren: function () {

**add this:**

```
if(addressList().length > 0){
    this.createRendererComponent(addressList()[0],this); */
}
else{
    _.each(addressList(), this.createRendererComponent, this);
}
return this;
```

},

**Create an override for:**

Vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/actions.html

**In your custom theme directory**

app/design/frontend/<Custom_Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address/actions.html

**Remove**